# 404 on request when session_id parameter is set

Tags: php, apache

I've a weird problem here.

When I pass some parameters to my server like this, everything its going fine.

```
http://test.com/check.php?token=123456&name=abcde
```

But when I add a parameter called session_id I get a 404

```
http://test.com/check.php?token=123456&name=abcde&session_id=0
```

Even if the parameter starts with session_id like I get 404 too

```
http://test.com/check.php?token=123456&name=abcde&session_idorsomething=0
```

The test code on check.php is as simple as this:

```
<?php var_dump($_GET);
```

I'm on Apache with PHP 7.2

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce with PHP 7.3.19 and Apache/2.4.38

Comment: My guess is there's some sort of a security routine on your server that lists `session_id*` as an undesirable query string variable and defaults to redirecting to error 404.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusAO Problem solved! The server had ModSecurity Enabled and a rule was blocking the request.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it was a simple as that. Throwing a 404 though, not very informative!